# How to add breakpoints in Node.JS / Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, jestjs

I am writing my code in JEST, I usually just run npm test from the package and it runs, how to add breakpoints in my test code to see the values of my variable?

Comment: It totally depends on what IDE you are using. Some of IDEs come with JS debugging for free and for others you might need to add js debugging plugins. You can always use console.log to print values anyway

Comment: I am using intellij. How do I set it up?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-jest.html#d570228e14